# What does "Caching service dependencies ..." mean?

Tags: tomcat, tomcat6

When I shut down Tomcat I get the following:

```
* Caching service dependencies...                 [ ok ]
* Stopping Tomcat...                              [ !! ]
```

What does *Caching service dependencies* mean?

Answer (score 3):

Are you using Gentoo? When you stop a service, Baselayout checks if there are other services depending on the service you are stopping. If it is the case, they are stopped before, in order of dependencies.

Whenever you restart a service in a distro based on Baselayout, it runs the `/sbin/depscan.sh` script, which stores dependencies in `/var/lib/init.d/depcache`. You will observe however that the message is not always printed. That's because while depscan.sh is run each time, it only creates a new cache if any file in `/etc/rc.d/`, `/etc/conf.d/`or the file `/etc/rc.conf` is changed.

For more details, refer to the script itself.

Comment: Yes, it's Gentoo. Is *caching* == *stopping*?

Comment: No, just updating the /var/lib/init.d/depcache file. All services are left in their current started/stopped state.